# Framework not found xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I built a framework and when trying to use it in another project gives me this error:

> ```
> ld: framework not found PSD
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

I'm using Xcode 7 and the .framework file is inside the project folder. I already tried changing non-recursive to recursive in paths and adding  the path manually, but it's not working.

Comment: make sure u include all frameworks in your project folder.  did u add all required frameworks ?

Comment: @Mr.T This is the only one apart from Cocoa Pods ones

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution, I wasn't building the Framework as Target

Comment: You didn't set the project dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I did add the dependencies into the main project but when I built the packet I wasn't doing it as a Target build.